# Page_Load issues on return from Paypal

Tags: .net, paypal

I have a fairly simple page that processes a payment to Paypal and then when returned from Paypal should display the users "order" to allow them to upload items and edit their order that they have paid for.

When I click on the link to return from Paypal some of my code doesn't seem to be running.  Do I have to process it different because Paypal is posting to my page?

I have my methods in the Page_Load part of the page, so when the page loads I check Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey() to get the Account ID of the logged in user and then use this with a separate function to get the Order ID.

When the page tries to run this code the returned Order ID is always a blank GUID.  I've output the Account ID to the screen and it's always correctly populated so I don't understand why the code returns a blank GUID.

```
accountID = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey()
Dim order As New orders
Dim orderID As String = order.SelectExistingPurchaseSeller(accountID, "2014/02/23")
```

If I leave the page maybe 3/4 seconds and press F5 then it displays as it should.

Am I missing something simple here?  I don't understand why it doesn't work the first time but then if I wait and refresh it runs my DB function as it should and returns the correct Order ID.

I've turned off Caching of this page by putting this at the top of the page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just as a further comment I've just added a 5 second wait by using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) and that seems to have sorted it but it should work instantly as soon as the page loads, why do I need to add a delay for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this myself.

Even though Paypal say their IPN is "Instant Payment Notification" it actually can take up to 10-20 seconds, because I'm checking as soon as the Paypal payment is put through sometimes the payment isn't complete.

Now I'm going to add some form of delay-check page to see if the order is complete before moving on.